# Given $1 \le |z| \le 7$ Find least and Greatest values of $\left|\frac{z}{4}+\frac{6}{z}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given $1 \le |z| \le 7$

Find least and Greatest values of $\left|\frac{z}{4}+\frac{6}{z}\right|$

I have taken $z=r e^{i \theta}$ $\implies$ $1 \le r \le 7$

Now $$\left|\frac{z}{4}+\frac{6}{z}\right|=\left|\frac{r \cos \theta}{4}+\frac{ir \sin \theta}{4}+\frac{6 \cos \theta}{r}-\frac{6 i \sin \theta}{r} \right|$$

So

$$\left|\frac{z}{4}+\frac{6}{z}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{16}+\frac{36}{r^2}+3 \cos (2\theta)}$$

any clue from here?

Comment: The function in the absolute value bars has a pole at $z = 6$.  And what happens at $z = \sqrt{24}$?

Comment: I think you solve this in the real numbers....$∣\frac z4|-|\frac 6z∣\le∣\frac z4+\frac 6z∣ \le ∣\frac z4|+|\frac 6z∣$  i.e. let $\cos 2\theta = \pm 1$ in your work above.

Answer (score 4):

$\left|\frac{z}{4}+\frac{6}{z}\right|=\left|\frac{z^2+24}{4z}\right|$

The function $f(z)=\frac{z^2+24}{4z}$ is analitic on $1\leq|z|\leq7$. Therefore, by the maximum modulus theorem its maximum absolute value is attained at the boundary. The boundary are the circles $|z|=1$ and $|z|=7$.

For $|z|=1$, observe that $z^2$ just travels the same circle. We have $|f(z)|=|z^2+24|/4$, which is maximum for $z=1$ or $z=-1$ (such that $z^2$ and $24$ point in the same direction).

For $|z|=7$, observe that $z^2$ travels the circle $|w|=49$. We have $|f(z)|=|z^2+24|/28$, which is maximum for $z=7$ or $z=-7$ (such that $z^2$ and 24 point in the same direction).

So, $f(7)=f(-7)$ seem to be the largest.

The minimum is zero at $f(\pm\sqrt{24}i)$.

Comment: Good solution, but you have two inaccuracies. (1) In the case $|z|=1$, you're missing $1/4$ in the expression for $|f(z)|$. (2) The zeroes are at $\pm\sqrt{-24}$.

Answer (score 1):

$|\frac {z}{4} + \frac {6}{z}| \ge 0$

I say that there exist a $z$ such that $1\le|z|\le 7$ and $\frac {z}{4} + \frac {6}{z} = 0$

and any such $z$ must minimize the objective.

$z = i 2\sqrt {6} $

To maximize the objective
$|\frac {z}{4} + \frac {6}{z}| \le |\frac {z}{4}| + |\frac {6}{z}|$

if $z$ is real then:
$|\frac {z}{4} + \frac {6}{z}| = |\frac {z}{4}| + |\frac {6}{z}|$

$z = 7$ maximises $|\frac {z}{4}| + |\frac {6}{z}|$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = r^2 \implies 1 \le x \le 49 $, and consider $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{16} + \dfrac{36}{x}\implies f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{16}- \dfrac{36}{x^2}\implies f'(x) = 0 \iff x = 24$, and $f(1) = 36+\dfrac{1}{16} = 36.0625, f(49) = \dfrac{49}{16}+\dfrac{36}{49}=3.8, f(24) = 3.$ $3\cos(2\theta)$ has a min of $-3$, and a max of $3$. Put these values together, we have: $\left|\dfrac{z}{4}+\dfrac{6}{z}\right|$ reaches a min of $\sqrt{3.8-3}\approx. 0.89$, and a max of $\sqrt{36.0625+3}=6.25$.

Comment: The minimum is definitely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

We want to find the minimum and maximum of

$\left| \dfrac{z}{4}+\dfrac{6}{z}\right|$

When $1\le |z|\le 7$

Let $z=x+iy$ and plug it in the given expression

$$\left| \dfrac{x+iy}{4}+\dfrac{6}{x+iy}\right|=\left| \dfrac{x+iy}{4}+\dfrac{6(x-iy}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\left|\frac{6 x}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{x}{4}+i\left(\frac{y}{4}-\frac{6 y}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right|$$

Which is 
$$r=\sqrt{\left(\frac{6 x}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{x}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{4}-\frac{6 y}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{r^4-48 r^2+96 x^2+576}}{4 r}$$
where $r^2=x^2+y^2$

As we have $1\le r\le 7$ let's plug $r=1$ and $r=7$ in the previous expression

for $r=1$ we get $\dfrac{ \sqrt{96 x^2+529}}{4}$ which is $\dfrac{25}{4}$ for $x=1$, maximum

for $r=7$ we get $\dfrac{\sqrt{96 x^2+625}}{28} $ which is $\dfrac{73}{28}$ for $x=7$, minimum

Hope this helps

**Edit**

Actually $\dfrac{z}{4}+\dfrac{6}{z}=0$ has a solution at $z=\pm 2 i \sqrt{6}$ whose module satisfies the condition $|z|\in[1,\;7]$ therefore that is the absolute minimum, zero.

Comment: And why "let's plug $r=1$ and $r=7$"? Why only the endpoints? If you're working with a function of a single real variable on a closed bounded interval, they may have extrema inside the interval, not only at the endpoints. Your edit partially salvages the answer, but it kinda came out of nowhere. If anything, it demonstrate that your solution was deficient.